# Issue sending triggered email in exactarget using Apex developer

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, json

I am trying to fire an ExactTarget triggered email using the Salesforce developer console. I am now getting the error "Problem initating message send during deserialization of JSON payload"

```
Http http2 = new Http();  
HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
req2.setMethod('POST');
  req2.setEndpoint('https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/b315a0e9-3618-e411-b6d6-b4b52f5cc7b0/send?access_token='+accessToken);
  req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');


 String SendId='"Address to send to"'   ;
 String MyEmail='"My Email"';
 String MyName='"My Name"';

  req2.setBody('To=' + SendId +'&From=' +MyEmail +'&From_Name=' +MyName);

 HttpResponse res2 = http.send(req2);
System.debug('Fulfillment service on Triggered Send '+ res2.getBody());
```

I believe my issue is setting up the JSON string to pass into the body for ET. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Body of the request in the question doesn't appear to be valid JSON.

From the [POST /messageDefinitionSends](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html) it should look more like:

```
{
    "From": {
        "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "Code@"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "Region": "West",
                "City": "Indianapolis",
                "State": "IN"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The [JSONGenerator](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm) should help in creating this for you. As a start:

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

gen.writeStartObject();

gen.writeFieldName('From');

gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('Address', MyEmail);
gen.writeStringField('Name', MyName);
gen.writeEndObject();

gen.writeFieldName('To');
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('Address', SendId);
// You might need to set the SubscriberKey etc... here?
gen.writeEndObject();

String pretty = gen.getAsString();
System.debug(pretty);

req2.setBody(pretty);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I added your snippet of code, as well as the subscriberkey section. However I am now getting the error     `Fulfillment service on Triggered Send {"requestId":"461fd7e9-ac39-4cfa-b67f-6414d71eeb4f","responses":[{"recipientSendId":"","hasErrors":true,"messages":["InvalidOrMissingTo"]}]}` What is that coming from?

Comment: @BalazsHoranyi Is the value in the `SendId` a valid email address?

Comment: @ DanielBallinger, Yes it is a valid email address.

Comment: @BalazsHoranyi I'm not sure how to fix the new error. Maybe try sending a hardcoded JSON string through first and then seeing if you can automate it after that. Was the messageDefinitionSends documentation I linked to the correct  API method?

Comment: Actually came down to a typo in my code. req.setHeader needed to be req2.setHeader. Thanks for all the help